# Does the exclusion of a header file a part of syntax error or not?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

```
#include 
int main()
{
//code
return 0;
}
```

Now here I haven't mentioned the name of any file so is it a part of compile-time error or the pre-processor would take care of it ,i.e. can this exclusion of header file considered a part of compile-time error(syntax error) or not ?

Comment: What does your compiler say about this? Mine tells me pretty clearly what it thinks about this code.

Answer (score 4):

The ISO C standard specifies the behaviour of both the preprocessor *and* compiler stages, there are various translation phases which make up the whole "chain" (see `C11 5.1.1.2 Translation phases` for details).

Since the standard `C11 6.10.2 Source file inclusion` specifically states the format of an include directive must be one of the forms:

```
# include <h-char-sequence> new-line
# include "q-char-sequence" new-line
# include pp-tokens new-line
```

(with the latter being subject to macro replacement but required to end up as one of the first two forms), that means what you have is definitely a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

The standard supports three forms of `#include`.

```
# include <h-char-sequence> new-line

# include "q-char-sequence" new-line

# include pp-tokens new-line
```

with the caveat that the last form must transform to one of the first two forms.

Your code is not any of the above three forms. Hence, it is not legal.

Answer (score 0):

1. `#include` is handled by the C pre-processor.
2. The line

   ```
   #include
   ```

   is incomplete.
3. Pre-processessing fails.

Conclusion:

No, this won't result in a "compiler-error" (as the compiling phase is not even reached) but in a pre-processor-error.